# Sony xperia enters in onDestroy method while changing activity

Tags: android

I'm testing my app in a samsung galaxy S4 mini and a Sony xperia T. While changing activity from MainActivity to SettingsActivity the sony xperia rises the onDestroy method after the onPause method. Unlike the S4, which rises only the onPause method.Any suggestions to explain this behaviour please? 
Sony xperia T android version 4.3

Samsung Galaxy S4 mini android version 4.2.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the Activity lifecycle: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Is `onStop()` called?

`onPause()` and `onResume()` are primarily for when an activity is being backgrounded.  When you switch to a new Activity the old one is available to be destroyed based on available memory and other parameters.  That is it.  Some devices will do it sooner rather than later.  Assume the lifecycle chart always hold true and make sure your Activities properly handle it.

Comment: I have reviewed the lifecycle. When an Activity is hidden, the onPause and onStop methods are call. You only call the onDestroy method when Activity finishes. In that case, the application is changing from the MainActivity to the PreferenceActivity. That action has to put the activity in the background, in the onStop method but not to call the onDestroy method. Indeed, the lifecycle into the S4 works perfectly.

Comment: OnStop occurs when backgrounded. OnDestroy occurs when the the backgrounded activity should be destroyed. Good to know it is following the lifecycle. Like i said earlier, the sony is probably just releasing the resources sooner than the s4.